# Notation for equivalence relations between pairs of numbers that have the same difference or the same quotient

Tags: notation, soft-question, arithmetic

I am looking for a sensible notation for the equivalence relations on pairs of natural numbers that can be used to introduce integers and rationals. Namely, I am using the following two equivalence relations that I for the moment denote $(\overset{+}{\sim})$ and $(\overset{\times}{\sim})$:

1. $(a, b)\overset{+}{\sim}(c, d)$ if and only if $a + d = b + c$,
2. $(a, b)\overset{\times}{\sim}(c, d)$ if and only if $a\times d = b\times c$.

[Correction: I plan to define the second equivalence relation only on pairs where the first element is nonzero, but the second can be zero (French naturals).]

I've just come up with the notation "$\overset{+}{\sim}$" and "$\overset{\times}{\sim}$". My questions are:

- is there any established notation for these equivalences?
- is there any reason to avoid the notation I used above? are there better options?

*Update.* Since these relations are analogous to [equipollence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipollence_(geometry)) in geometry, maybe "$\overset{+}{\bumpeq}$" and "$\overset{\times}{\bumpeq}$" or  "$\underset{+}{\bumpeq}$" and "$\underset{\times}{\bumpeq}$" will be better?

Comment: Seems fine, except the second equivalence relation needs to be limited to nonzero naturals to obtain the (positive) rationals.

Comment: @SammyBlack, indeed. In fact, i think to allow the second element of the pair to be zero, but require the first one to be nonzero.